# I get nothing when I run the program. Just gives me my exe aplication and thats it. How Do I fix it?

Tags: c++, exe

Code compiles fine with no errors.
But when running a program it just gives me exe program and program ends with no input or out put.
How Do I dix it. Help me out please.
Beginner programmer.
Code is not finished yet only with the output section.
What is my next steps.
Comments are appreciated.
..........................................................................................................----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Code down below

```
const int MONTH_QUANTITY = 12;
typedef double Rainfalls[MONTH_QUANTITY];

// Function prototypes
double findTotal(Rainfalls, double);
double findMonthlyAverage(Rainfalls, double);
double findHighest(Rainfalls, double);
double findLowest(Rainfalls, double);
void getUserInput(Rainfalls, double);

// Main function
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Rainfalls monthArray;
    void getUserInput(Rainfalls, double);
    double findTotal(Rainfalls, double);
    int monthlyHighest;
    int monthlyLowest;
    double monthlyAverage;
    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(Rainfalls monthArray, double MonthlyRainfalls)
{
    std::cout << "Please enter total rainfalls over a period of 12 month\n";
    for(int rainfalls = 0; rainfalls < MONTH_QUANTITY; rainfalls++)
    {
        std::cout << "Month"<< (rainfalls + 1) << ": ";
        std::cin >> monthArray[rainfalls];
        while(monthArray[rainfalls] < 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Error! Negative numbers are not allowed";
            std::cout << "Please enter amount of rainfall above or equal to 0\n";
            std::cin >> monthArray[rainfalls];
        }
    }
}
 
double findTotal(Rainfalls totalMonths, double totalRainfalls)
{
    double totalRainfall = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MONTH_QUANTITY; i++)
    totalRainfall += totalMonths[i];
    
    return totalRainfall;
}

double findMonthlyAverage(Rainfalls monthlyAverage, double quantity)
{
    double average = 0;
    for(int rainfall = 0; rainfall < quantity; rainfall++)
    
        average += monthlyAverage[rainfall];
        
        return (average / quantity);
}

int findHighest(Rainfalls array, int max)
{
    int highest = array[0];
    for(int index = 1; index < max; index++)
    {
        if(array[index] > highest)
        highest = array[index];
    }
    return highest;
}   


int findLowest(Rainfalls array, int max)
{
    int lowest = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index < lowest; index++)
    {
        if(array[index] < lowest)
        lowest = array[index];
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

Comment: When you're _invoking_ a function, you don't need to specify its return type. In the body of `main`, `void getUserInput(Rainfalls, double);` is a function declaration, not a function invocation. The call would just look like `getUserInput(monthArray, ????)`. I say `????` because there's no `double` for you to pass as the second argument, but also your function never uses that argument so it should probably be removed from the declaration.

Comment: Similarly you don't actually use the `totalRainfalls` argument in `findTotal`, it should probably just be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no statement to do anything (other than `return 0;`) in your `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Rainfalls monthArray;
    void getUserInput(Rainfalls, double);
    double findTotal(Rainfalls, double);
    int monthlyHighest;
    int monthlyLowest;
    double monthlyAverage;
    return 0;
}
```

It contains just declarations of variables and functions.

The next step will be write some code in your `main()` function to do some calculation that you want.

Comment: `Rainfalls` isn't undisclosed, it's a `typedef` for a `double[12]` array.